# Wiped Qosmio hard drive, any chance recovery partition still these?

Tags: windows, boot, toshiba-laptop, toshiba-hard-drive

I purchased a used Qosmio x70 which was slower than what I expected,  So I tried resetting it to factory settings but it ended with me deleting everything on the hard drive
I found this option in Windows boot menu under Toshiba Maintainance tools

So is there any chance I can reset the laptop to factory settings and how can I confirm if recovery partition is still there or deleted with the rest of the files

P.S.
Whenever I try to boot now I get the "media check failed - No bootable devices found" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different options for checking if it wiped all partitions on the HDD. You could connect the HDD to another computer and if there is any partitions windows will recognize them and show it in the my computer area as a HDD to select. If it did wipe everything, windows will let you know you need to format it to be able to use it. Or you can use a windows install disc and install windows on it, and windows will give you an option to format the HDD before installing if anything is left on it, or just give you the option to install windows on it if it is blank.

Comment: Thanks @Frostalf for your help. I just could not take out my HDD so I just installed a new version of windows and checked the HDD and it was completely wiped and the recovery partition was no longer there